# I appear to have got two serverfault accounts, how do I get them merged?

Tags: support, status-completed

https://serverfault.com/users/1468/rob and https://serverfault.com/users/49805/rob are both me, I'm not sure what's happened to result in me having multiple identities.

Does anyone know how/if I can get them combined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  e-Mail team@serverfault.com.

Comment: I hadn't got round to emailing team@ but it looks like Jeff has already sorted it. Accepted Answer to you though as it would've solved it I'm sure, if I'd been less lazy. Oh and +1 =)